# How to start a server on a free port from within a client script?

Tags: client-server, port

I have a (python) script that must start a server. The server should be using a free port obviously, and the python script must know this port in order to communicate with it.

Question is, how do I make sure this is the case?

- You cannot determine the free port in the python script, and pass it to the server, because in the meanwhile another application could have taken the port.
- You cannot let the server choose a port, because then the port is unknown to the script.

This looks like a pretty common problem, so I suppose it has been tackled before.
What is the neatest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of preferred ports, and try them in the order of preference. This list will of course be known to both client and server.

I suspect you are picking a low port. Since most of the lower ports (close to 1024 or below) already have [dedicated applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers), you want to avoid these.

If you are using a higher port the likeliness of a collision is negligible, which I think is the common solution.

Comment: How and where should I try these ports?

Comment: Define a list of ports.
When you start the server, iterate through the list and try to listen to every port, until you find a free port. 
When you connect to the server, iterate through the list (in the same order) and try to connect to each port. Then verify that you have connected to the correct application with some kind of hand-shake.